# How to catch OS-COMMAND results in Progress-4GL?

Tags: command-line, openedge, progress-4gl

I'm using the logging facilities, as described in [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65406908/how-to-do-logging-in-openedge-progress):

```
OUTPUT TO VALUE("C:\Temp_Folder\logfile.txt").
...
PUT UNFORMATTED "Start : Check-zones" SKIP.
...
OUTPUT CLOSE.
```

This is working fine.

Now I would like to add the results of an `OS-COMMAND` in the output file.
I've already tried the following: (putting the results in a newly to be created file)

```
OS-COMMAND NO-WAIT VALUE("WMIC printer get name, deviceID >> C:\Temp_Folder\Printers.txt").
```

This is working fine.
So, I know the command is working fine. However, the following is not working:

```
OS-COMMAND NO-WAIT VALUE("WMIC printer get name, deviceID >> C:\Temp_Folder\LogFile.txt").
```

This is obvious, because `C:\Temp_Folder\Logfile.txt` is locked for writing by the progress application, so the shell, opened by `OS-COMMAND` can't write to that file.

In order to overcome this, I would like to catch the results of the `OS-COMMAND`'s results.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately back in the dark ages when os-command was designed, it was considered useful to suppress all errors.

You can either start a batch file and let that do some “guaranteed” output error handling, see https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/21039

Or (since you are on Windows) you can use the .Net [system diagnostics process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process) class (which you will want to wrap in your own method or function to simplify use):

```
DEFINE VARIABLE oProcess   AS System.Diagnostics.Process NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE lcstderr   AS LONGCHAR    NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE lcstdout   AS LONGCHAR    NO-UNDO.

oProcess = NEW System.Diagnostics.Process().

oProcess:StartInfo:FileName = "wmic.exe".
oProcess:StartInfo:Arguments = "printer get name, deviceID".
oProcess:StartInfo:CreateNoWindow         =  TRUE.
oProcess:StartInfo:UseShellExecute        =  FALSE.
oProcess:StartInfo:RedirectStandardError  =  TRUE.
oProcess:StartInfo:RedirectStandardOutput =  TRUE.
oProcess:Start().

lcstdout = oProcess:StandardOutput:ReadToEnd().
lcstderr = oProcess:StandardError:ReadToEnd().

oProcess:WaitForExit().

lcstdout = lcstdout + oProcess:StandardOutput:ReadToEnd().
lcstderr  = lcstderr + oProcess:StandardError:ReadToEnd().
```

Comment: The reason this is working, is that there is some file on my PC, making a class like `System.Diagnostics.Process` accessible from my AppBuilder. Do you know where I can find that file?

Comment: It’s the .Net class, there’s an entire manual on the subject. https://documentation.progress.com/output/ua/OpenEdge_latest/index.html#page/dvngp%2Faccessing-and-managing-.net-classes-from-abl.html%23