# How can I check a customer's PC for presence of .Net related DLLs?

Tags: .net, configuration, version

As mentioned in the accepted answer on a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65518478/which-activex-control-ocx-file-handles-wmi), I now know how to use .Net classes (like System Management) in order to do some .Net related programming in my Progress-4GL program.

As mentioned in the answer, this development is based on a DLL (in this particular case, System.Management.dll).

A simple search on my PC revealed several instances of that file:

```
Prompt>dir /S /B System.Management.dll
C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v3.5\Profile\Client\System.Management.dll
...

C:\Windows\WinSxS\msil_system.management_b03f5f7f11d50a3a_4.0.15744.161_none_b6b533cbb2171a8a\System.Management.dll
```

Obviously it makes no sense programming something on my PC, based on some DLL, present on my PC, when I want that program to work on a customer's computer while I don't know anything about that customer's computer (OK, I know it's a Windows computer).

What are the prerequisites for a customer's computer in order to be able to use .Net related classes and what's an easy way to check those prerequisites?

**Edit after small investigation**

In the meantime I found out that I can find the list of installed .Net frameworks on a PC, using this commandline command:

```
reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP
```

How can I know the link between those versions and the DLL I'm referring to?

Comment: .NET comes with all DLLs included. Any version will do

Comment: And what about .Net class versions? Those should be dependent on the DLLs, aren't they?

Comment: Yes, whichever version is loaded in the .exe will be used, unless you are using version < 4.0 then you get Framework 2.0 loaded side by side

Comment: @Charlieface: please put your comment as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.NET Framework/Core comes with all DLLs included. Any version will do, unless the app has been configured to only use a specific version.

`MSCORLIB.dll` version 1.1, 2.0 (that's for Framework up til 3.5) and 4.0 (up til 4.8) would run side-by-side in the same exceution space.